# Problems connecting pycharm to remote interpreter via docker

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to connect pycharm 2016.2 professional to remote python interpreter via docker. I have docker for windows version 1.12.0-rc2-beta20 (the one that uses hyper-v on windows 10; not virtualbox). In pycharm, there's dialog that asks for the docker API URL which is by default populated with: https://192.168.99.100:2376

But that doesn't connect. I also tried localhost:2376 and 10.0.75.0:2376 (10.0.75.0 is the internal IP for vEthernet (DockerNAT)) and they do not work. Is the integration just not supported with the non-virtualbox docker or am I entering the wrong thing?

Comment: I tried this: http://localhost:2375 and it worked but then ran into other problems. Console doesn't seem to work and skeleton update keeps re-ruinning.